# SQL Server - Schedule Jobs Getting data from one database to another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am planning to schedule a job on one my database and which basically runs at 5:00 PM everyday.

Database 1 : TestOne   TableName: MyTable

Database 2 : TestTwo   TableName: MyTable

My schedule job resides in TestOne and Inserts into MyTable and the values has
to come from TestTwo.MyTable.

Is there any example that's available that does something similar? Is this as simple as getting an user from TestOne.MyTable access rights on TestTwo.MyTable?

I appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Provide a little bit more info - the size of master-table, if you need the incremental updates, is it possible to delete all the data in target table (any FKeys)?

Comment: Are you using SSIS?  Are the databases on the same server or different servers?

Comment: @Oleg Dok - Currently the tables can be deleted and recreated. I have suggested the incremental updates.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek - SSIS can be an option. Both databases are in different servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some simple scenarios (assuming - i can do the truncate):

```
truncate table TestOne.dbo.MyTable
insert TestOne.dbo.MyTable(fieldslist)
select fieldslist from TestTwo.dbo.MyTable
```

**OR**

using the merge (more like the incremental, but needs an unique key):

```
MERGE TestOne.dbo.MyTable T
USING (SELECT fieldslist from TestTwo.dbo.MyTable) S
ON T.UniqueKey = S.UniqueKey
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  field1=S.field1,
  ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    insert (fieldslist)
    VALUES(fieldslist)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE DELETE;
```

Answer (score 1):

The user needs to have enough permissions on both databases, of course (read from `TestTwo.MyTable` / write to `TestOne.MyTable`).

The only other thing you need is the correct syntax to access one database from the other.
If the job resides in `TestOne`, the query has to look like this (out of my head, untested):

```
use TestOne

insert into MyTable (Column1, Column2, ...)
select Column1, Column2, ...
from TestTwo.dbo.MyTable
```

The important thing when accessing other databases is the order: `Database.Schema.Table`
In my example (`TestTwo.dbo.MyTable`) I used the default schema `dbo` - you need to change that in my query if your table has a different schema.